# Advices for a simple CMS

Tags: html, content-management-system

I have a single page website built on top of Bootstrap that I use as a template to publish written articles. I have to write a new one every time I copy the page, and edit the html. I would like to speed up these voyages into the tags hell, and also make this page editable from someone that is just a user, not a web designer.
I don't want to use Wordpress, or any other major league CMS, I just want to have an admin interface that I (or someone else) can use to edit the text on my page. Any suggestion on how to start to achieve this? 
Is there any open source tool to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

From what I believe, there are a lot of open-source rich text editor tools that you can adopt in your own site:

https://quilljs.com/

http://substance.io/

https://draftjs.org/